# Spring Boot - Thymeleaf - New project does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, new-project

I need help to start a new project with spring boot.

I used spring tool suite 4 "spring starter project".

I followed all the steps of the guide correctly, but once I run localhost:8080 it tells me that it's impossible to reach the site.
In problem's section, i've 0 problems and warnings.

**my pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.progettoThymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>progettoThymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyNewProject</name>
    <description>Nuov progetto ThymeLeaf</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**My .log file:**

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.debug 2 0 2020-10-08 21:09:12.334
!MESSAGE Unable to find location of java.lang.Thread.setName() in debuggee JVM, for type java.lang.Thread
```

Thank you

**THE NEW CONSOLE OUTPUT:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)

2020-10-08 21:43:13.953  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] i.p.start.MyNewProjectApplication        : Starting MyNewProjectApplication on griccipw10 with PID 19656 (C:\Progetto Thymeleaf\Workspace\MyNewProject\target\classes started by gricci in C:\Progetto Thymeleaf\Workspace\MyNewProject)
2020-10-08 21:43:13.960  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] i.p.start.MyNewProjectApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-10-08 21:43:14.051  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-10-08 21:43:14.051  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-10-08 21:43:15.087  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2020-10-08 21:43:15.105  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2020-10-08 21:43:15.110  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2020-10-08 21:43:15.199  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-10-08 21:43:15.212  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-10-08 21:43:15.215  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-10-08 21:43:15.615  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-10-08 21:43:15.627  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-10-08 21:43:15.627  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
2020-10-08 21:43:15.949  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-10-08 21:43:15.949  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1898 ms
2020-10-08 21:43:16.267  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-10-08 21:43:16.283 DEBUG 19656 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2020-10-08 21:43:16.365 DEBUG 19656 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2020-10-08 21:43:16.399 DEBUG 19656 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2020-10-08 21:43:16.408 DEBUG 19656 --- [  restartedMain] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2020-10-08 21:43:16.601  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-10-08 21:43:16.751  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-10-08 21:43:16.851  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2020-10-08 21:43:16.852  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-10-08 21:43:16.852  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2020-10-08 21:43:16.903  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-10-08 21:43:16.923  INFO 19656 --- [  restartedMain] i.p.start.MyNewProjectApplication        : Started MyNewProjectApplication in 3.491 seconds (JVM running for 6.366)
2020-10-08 21:43:20.841  INFO 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-08 21:43:20.841  INFO 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-08 21:43:20.841 DEBUG 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2020-10-08 21:43:20.851 DEBUG 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2020-10-08 21:43:20.851  INFO 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
2020-10-08 21:43:20.881 DEBUG 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/home", parameters={}
2020-10-08 21:43:20.896 DEBUG 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-10-08 21:43:20.900 DEBUG 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2020-10-08 21:43:20.901 DEBUG 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-10-08 21:43:20.911 DEBUG 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2020-10-08 21:43:20.914 DEBUG 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2020-10-08 21:43:20.960 DEBUG 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2020-10-08 21:43:20.966 DEBUG 19656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Screen of my browser:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T0Mb.png)

**HomeController.java :**

```
package it.progettoThymeleaf.start;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

public class HomeController {
    
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String getHome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Benvenuti nel mio nuovo progetto Thymeleaf!");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**home.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Gianluca's New Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 th:text=${message}></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Project package explorer screen:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVBsi.png)

Comment: can you add build.gradle or pom.xml in question?

Comment: Also when you hit `localhost:8080`, does something get printed in logs? If yes can you share that too.

Comment: `logging.level.root=debug` put this in your application.properties to get more logs and post them all to your question. Along with the pom.xml/build.gradel. Also show us which controller endpoint your are calling

Comment: @wak786 added pom.xml

Comment: @gtiwari333 I already have this on my application.properties:

logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG

Comment: @wak786 .log:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.debug 2 0 2020-10-08 21:05:29.396
!MESSAGE Unable to find location of java.lang.Thread.setName() in debuggee JVM, for type java.lang.Thread

Comment: Can you post the exact content that you are seeing on the browser?

Comment: @gtiwari333 added screen

Comment: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http). You are using default port 8080 but based on the screenshot you are trying to access 8081

Comment: Use 8080 in browser to access the app that you are running

Comment: @gtiwari333 sorry mate, now i have a new console output and screen of browser

Comment: What do you have for the   '/home' mapping? Show us your controllers and the templates under resources folder. You are getting 400 because you don't have anything configured

Comment: @gtiwari333 added homeController.java, home.html and package explorer screen

Comment: `public class HomeController {` is missing @Controller

Comment: @gtiwari333 OMG mate!!! It works!!! Really thank you!!
But why the lack of the annotation break the application?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by 'break the application'. The annotation help spring to see your class and configure the MVC url mappings

Comment: @gtiwari333 thank you mate!

Answer (score 1):

Your namespace in home.html is incomplete http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a project on my local and faced the same issue.

I got it resolved by adding an `html` file under templates folder.
Basically, this is the place where your `thymeleaf` templates will live. Adding a screenshot.

[image]

Add this to your properties file if you want to access home page from `/home`

`server.servlet.context-path=/home`

Comment: In templates i already have home.html , does not work @wak786

Comment: Okay cool. See this line from logs `Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''`. So basically ur home page is rendering from `localhost:8080` and not from `localhost:8080/home` because your context path is empty.

Comment: Add context path property to application.properties. I have edited the answer accordingly.